# "Line not available" in android debugging

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar, eclipse-adt

I have an Android library source code and .jar archive for that library. I also have and Android app that makes use of that library. My library source code and Android app are in the same Eclipse workspace. So, I added .jar archive to build path of the Android app, and attached source code to that .jar archive.

[image]

I am able to look inside the functions I call in my app, but when I am debugging, I can not step through the functions from the library that I am calling. In the debugger it says "line: not available".

[image]

[image]

How can I make it so that I can step through the code in the library? I know that in the Java compiler settings for the Android library, I have to check the box on "Add line number attributed to generated class files", which I already did for both Android app and Android library.

[image]

Did I miss something? Why do I still get "line: not available" message in debugger and can't step through the code from library?

Both library and app are compiled with Java 1.6. Android app's build target is Android 5.1.1, and libraries' build target is Android 4.0.3 .

Comment: you can check availability of debug information with `javap -l` on compiled classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured it out. I was using .jar archive for this library, but this .jar archive wasn't generated by me and apparently did not allow for line numbers to be added to generated class files. I exported my own .jar archive, linked source code to .jar archive, and was able to debug the code without any issues.